# Alternative/Appropriate word for hypocrite

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What do you call a person who says something but does something else in action? Although this may apply to some thoughts/ideas that the person shares and not all of them.
Labelling the person as “hypocrite”, would it be appropriate in this case?

Comment: The word is HYPOCRITE - you can look up synonyms for it. Yes, it can be appropriate to use it of one aspect of a person's behaviour.

Comment: @KateBunting But isn't then all people hypocrites? Or probably it can be interpreted in this way: Like if a person advocates an idea but then does something else => Hypocrite. But if a person makes a statement once or twice which he doesn't follow than he cannot be called hypocrite

Comment: I said 'It _can_ be appropriate', not that it was always appropriate! You can soften it by saying "He's a bit hypocritical when he says X", or "She doesn't always practise what she preaches".

Comment: This reminds me of *All Cretans are liars* - an assertion which is "paradoxical" ***if and only if*** uttered by a Cretan. The reason such things lead to nonsense is because ***in the real world*** there's no such thing as a person who lies or is hypocritical **100%** of the time. It makes no sense to label someone as a hypocrite without specifying ***in what respect***, because they can't be hypocritical in ***every*** respect.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments, I understand the question to be, "How hypocritical does someone have to be before it's right to call him a hypocrite?"

This is a language site, not an ethics site, so my answer is given on that basis.

First, it's helpful to see that this question applies to a wide range of words. If I take a towel from a hotel, am I a thief? Or am I only a thief if I regularly rob banks? How often or how well do I have to play the piano before you can call me a pianist?

What I would say is that it's not helpful to have a range of different nouns to describe different levels of activity or character. My instinct is that the English language doesn't function that way. Instead, we use the same word but qualify its meaning with adjectives, adverbs, clauses and so on.

So everyone who plays the piano at any level is a pianist. But one person may be a concert pianist, another person only a casual pianist. The additional words explain where on the spectrum of piano playing each person fits.

It's the same with **hypocrite**. As far as I know there's no word with the meaning, "a person who is only hypocritical in one area of their life." It's simply hypocrite. But what we do instead is to qualify that sentence with adjectives or with extra clauses that define the scope of the hypocrisy. Here are some examples:

1. She is a hypocrite.
2. He is the biggest hypocrite I know.
3. She was being slightly hypocritical there.
4. He lied about how much progress they were making at work, which I think is rather hypocritical when last week he was criticising the other office for the same thing.
5. It's seriously hypocritical of her to punish the children for swearing when she swears so much herself.